# Decay of a function which is integrable against an exponentially growing function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a measurable function and suppose there exists $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\varepsilon\left|x\right|}f(x)dx<\infty$.

Is it possible to deduce from this that $f(x)\leq Ce^{-\delta\left|x\right|}$ for $\left|x\right|$ big enough for some $\delta>0$ (perfectly fine if $\delta$ is much smaller than $\varepsilon$)?

There obviously has to be sequences $x_{n}$ along which this is true, but I can't get a handle on the potential irregularities of $f(x)$ in the sense that it could be big on sets of small measure.

Any suggestions as to what sort of result is possible would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Alternatively, is it possible to say something about the integrability of $e^{\delta\left|x\right|}f(x)^{p}$ for $p=2$ and beyond.

Comment: As you have said yourself: $f$ can be very big on sets of very small measure. In general, such an inequality will not hold. You would need some further assumptions, like uniform continuity.

Comment: @Dominik. Thanks for your comment - I was afraid of that. What about proving something like $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\delta\left|x\right|}f(x)^{2}dx<\infty$? I feel like the "overall decay" of f should be enough for this even if it occasionally behaves badly, but I'm not making any progress trying to prove it.

Comment: Can we assume that $f$ is nonnegative?

Comment: @Dominik. Yes, certainly! My motivation was to think of it as a density of a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't conclude this. Let $f$ be a density that has a value proportional to $\exp(\exp(n) - 2n)$ in an $\exp(-\exp(n))$-interval around each integer $n$ and is zero otherwise. Then $\exp(x) f(x)$ is integrable, but $\exp(\delta x) f(x)^{1 + \varepsilon}$ is not integrable for any $\varepsilon > 0$ (not even for negative $\delta$).

Comment: Many thanks for the counterexample! Looks like an apriori $L^{\infty}$ bound could be quite helpful in ruling out this kind of behavior.